# C++ Endless Loop Bottleneck?

Tags: c++, loops, infinite-loop

I plan on writing a program where I take a number and compare it to a mathematical theorem to test if it's true or false, and then add one to the number to test the next number. Assume I do this in a massive loop where the loop ends if int == 100,000,000.

Is there any default bottleneck that's going to be in the .exe after it's compiled, or will this push my processor to max load until it completes the loop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question depends entirely on the mathematical theorem you're trying to prove for each number. Care to share?

Comment: This is just a loop, nothing else. On todays computers 1 mln is done in no time. The bottleneck might be in the code for testing your theorem.

Comment: @TomasLycken: It doesn't depend on that at all. It just depends on how the OS chooses to schedule a CPU-bound process.

Comment: @TomasLycken I didn't have anything specific in mind. Let's say something like a prime number test, where (n-1)! ≡ -1 (mod p)

Comment: It may be wise to break the loop up into chunks, where one CPU core proves 1-10,000,000, the next proves 10,000,001 to 20,000,001 etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't exhaust the available RAM which would cause swapping and an IO bottleneck, your program should be CPU bound.

One CPU core will be almost 100 % busy and if you use multiple threads or processes you can keep the whole CPU almost 100 % busy. I'm saying almost because most likely your operating system will have to do some housekeeping for a tiny fraction of the available time.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, Peter. I'm fairly new to programming and am just trying to teach myself; what would be the best way to avoid maxing out RAM? I didn't really think that this type of program would be heavy on memory use.

Comment: I mentioned the RAM just in case. Some mathematical algorithms use huge matrices others big arrays.

Comment: @elgo2006: Taking your example of (p!), you'd have to realize that that can be a big number. E.g. for p=1000, you'd be looking at a number that's some 3000 digits long. That's a whopping 10.000 bits, or 1.25 kilobyte. OK, perhaps it's not that big compared to the millions of kilobytes of RAM..

Answer (score 1):

As long as you dont use multithreading, it should be difficult to push your processor to max load. More loops only take more time, not more CPU load.